# For loop stops execution of a batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a Batch file, in this batch file I need to move all of my old folders to a Backup folder.

If a execute this command directly it work :

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b D:\app\*_2*') do move D:\app\%a D:\app\Backup\
```

But if I use it in a batch, the batch close itself and don't perform the rest of the script.

Any idea?

Comment: In a batch file, use `%%a`, not `%a`

Comment: Besides the `%%` issue, your code will fail as soon as at least one path contains a space or special characters like `(`, `)`, `&`,..., unless you put quotes around the paths and add the option string `"delims= eol=|"` (disable delimiters which default to space and tab, change the end-of-line character to one invalid for file paths/names (default: `;`, which is valid in file paths/names))...

Comment: You can also read the help file for the `FOR` command and you would have seen it plain as day.  You only had to read the first 10 lines of the help file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by [parameter substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in batch files. To have `%a` passed to the `for` command in a batch script, you have to escape the `%` character using `%%`.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b D:\app\*_2*') do move D:\app\%%a D:\app\Backup\
```

See also: https://ss64.com/nt/for.html